# Spring Scheduled annotation with zone EST, not working

Tags: spring, cron, scheduled-tasks, spring-annotations

I am trying to create a scheduler to run in EST timezone. For that, I have added @Scheduled annotation upon the scheduled method. The method is given below. I want this method to run daily at 05:00 am EST on Mon-Friday, but it runs at 3:30 am IST (6:00 pm EST).

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 5 * * MON-FRI", zone = "EST")
public void jobRunDaily() {
  logger.info("jobRunDaily : called");
  this.sendEmailDaily();
}
```

Comment: Try using zone in contient/region format something like "America/New_York"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#zone--), `zone` accepts IDs that are valid for `TimeZone.getTimeZone(String)`.

In `TimeZone` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html?is-external=true#getTimeZone-java.lang.String-) you will find the following for such method:

> the ID for a TimeZone, either an abbreviation such as "PST", a full name such as "America/Los_Angeles", or a custom ID such as "GMT-8:00". Note that the support of abbreviations is for JDK 1.1.x compatibility only and full names should be used.

Meaning that full names should be used instead of your "EST" abbreviation.